# get section cell Text on custom cells button click?

Tags: iphone

How can i get section cell text on custom cell button click.

is this possible?

Thank you,

Comment: i have tableview with custom cell and custom uibutton each and every row with Section like A, B, C, D

so how can i get cell text which i click on custom button.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are drawing the cell set the tag on the button as an index into the array of data that you are displaying

```
[acceptAnswersButton setTag:indexPath.row]
```

Then when the button is clicked you can get the tag from the action that is called as the button will be passed as a parameter.

---

If you add the tag to the button for each row. Then in the associated action you have the index into the array that you got the text from to retrieve it again.

```
arrayText = {"one", "two", "three"}
```

This means that the cellForRowAtIndexPath will set the tag for each button as

```
row1ButtonTag=0
row2ButtonTag=1
row3ButtonTag=2
```

and when the action is called you will have access to the button that called the action and therefore access to the index into the array

```
(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender {
    NSString *theTextIWasLookingFor = [arrayText objectAtIndex:((UIButton*)sender).tag];
}
```

Comment: Hello,

i already used this code, but i want to select cell "text" on custom button click

Thank you